# Text rotation in the table doesn't work on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, asp.net

Hi I have a table and would like to make the text of header rotates to specific degree. I searched the web and  found the css script. The css script is mentioned at many website. However it only works on IE. would some one tell me to make it work. Thanks.

there is my code:

```
<head>
        <style>
            #customers {
              font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
              border-collapse: collapse;
              width: 50%;
            }

            #customers td, #customers th {
              border: 1px solid #ddd;
              padding: 8px;
            }

            #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

            #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

            #customers th {
              padding-top: 12px;
              padding-bottom: 12px;
              text-align: left;
              background-color: #4CAF50;
              color: white;
              height:130;
            }

            .text-rotation {              
                transform:rotate(-65deg);
                -ms-transform:rotate(-65deg); /* IE 9 */
                -moz-transform:rotate(-65deg); /* Firefox */
                -webkit-transform:rotate(-65deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
                -o-transform:rotate(-65deg); /* Opera */
            }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <br><br><br>
        <div><h3>Rotate Text</h3></div>
        <div>
            <table id='customers'>
                <tr class="text-rotation">
                    <td>Week Number</td>
                    <td class=" text-rotation">Start Date</td>
                    <td class=" text-rotation">Chilliwack</td>
                    <td class=" text-rotation">Fort St. John</td>
                    <td class=" text-rotation">Kamloops</td>
                <tr class="talgnC">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>07 Jan 2019</td>
                    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr class="talgnC">
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>14 Jan 2019</td>
                    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td> 
                </tr>
   </div>
</body>
```

There is the table show in Chrome  Version 81.0.4044.113
[image: Show in the Chrome]

Comment: It is working . I tried in jsfiddle and here in snipped. Both of them works

Comment: @Çağrı I added the photo to show how the table look like on Chrome

Comment: Do u want that it rotates in td column ?

Comment: @Çağrı I just want to rotate  on the first row form second column to last Column